# partitions and replication_factor

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a kafka-cluster of 3 nodes in 3 different AWS availablitiy zone. So 1 broker per zone.
I produce 70 million messages in a burst once per day by 32 producers.
all the same topic.
I have one consumer that consumes this and works off the work.
Currently I have it set naivly to 1 partition and 1 replication factor.
I see that only 1 broker has been receiving all messages from all 32 producers.

Now I am looking into how to spread the load between the brokers and get some redundancy and remembered that I have partitions and replication factor at 1 and was wondering to what to set it to achieve my goal.

Would replication_factor=2 and num_partitions=6 be good?
Guessing that I have every message safely on 2 brokers for redundancies and 2 partitions per broker for some scaling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consumers and producers can only ever read/write to one partition. Replicas only help when brokers are down.

That being said, without more information about what data you're sending, you should definitely use far more than 1 partition unless you need absolute ordering. Six seems small for handling millions of events

Comment: This answer misses one other critical item - When using rack aware kafka brokers + consumers, you can consume from the closest replica. This can be useful when your application is particularly latency sensitive, or if you have a cloud deployment and care about cross-az traffic costs. Another good reason to increase replication factor.

You will also need to be careful about much your app can tolerate produce-consume latency, asn the chosen follwer replica may have some lag.

There are some further details and articles on this topic, if it applies to your use case.

Comment: Question had tagged `kafka-python`. I'm not sure if that supports replica fetching or rack awareness